# How do I return to the beginning of the function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make the `Settings()` function return to the `Menu()` function, but the `Settings()` just continues from where it was called.
I just need it to return to the top of the `Menu()` function.

Here's the code:

```py
def Menu():
   Clear()
   print("Hello, world!")
   print("\n1. Settings")
   print("2. Exit")
   Choice = input("\n>")
   try:
       type(int(Choice))
   except Exception as e: 
       print("Oh no!\n I`ve encountered an error!" + e)
       Menu()
   if Choice == 1:
       Settings()
   if Choice == 2:
       exit(0)

def Settings():
   Menu()
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Use a loop in the `Menu()` function, and break out of the loop when they select Exit.

Comment: You are checking if it's possible to cast `Choice` to an int, but even it succeeded, `Choice` is still a string. So your `if`s never execute...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a while loop, and use the string method `.isdigit()` to check if the user entered a number. Additionally, you should also check if the choice is a valid menu option.

Note: Don't forget to cast choice to an int or your conditionals will not execute.

```py
def Menu():
    while True:
        Clear()
        print('Hello, world!\n')
        print('1. Settings')
        print('2. Exit')
        
        choice = input('> ')
        if choice.isdigit() and int(choice) in {1, 2}:
            choice = int(choice)
            break
        else:
            print("Please enter 1 or 2")
            input('press enter to continue...')
    
    
    if choice == 1:
        Settings()
    if choice == 2:
        exit(0)
```

If you've already checked that the user's input is a valid option and you've turned it into an int, then you could use a dictionary like so:

```py
switch = {
    1: Settings
    2: exit
}
```

and then you could replace if statements in your Menu like so:

```py
def Menu():
    while True:
        Clear()
        print('Hello, world!\n')
        print('1. Settings')
        print('2. Exit')
        
        choice = input('> ')
        if choice.isdigit() and int(choice) in {1, 2}:
            choice = int(choice)
            break
        else:
            print("Please enter 1 or 2")
            input('press enter to continue...')
    
    switch[choice]()
```

Comment: Wow, I didnt really know that dictionaries existed, and this is a really detailed answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The type of `Choice` is `str` so it's not able to compare correctly and the comparison always fails,
typecast the value to int with `Choice = int(Choice)`

```
def Menu():
   Clear()
   print("Hello, world!")
   print("\n1. Settings")
   print("2. Exit")
   Choice = input("\n>")
   try:
       Choice = (int(Choice))
   except Exception as e:
       print("Oh no!\n I`ve encountered an error!" + e)
       Menu()
   if Choice == 1:
       Settings()
   if Choice == 2:
       exit(0)

def Settings():
   Menu()
```

Comment: Small correction - it's not that *it's not able to compare*, it's just that the comparison ***always*** fails...

Comment: Oh yeah i forgot about that. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

Just simply loop Menu() forever:

```
def Menu():
   Clear()
   print("Hello, world!")
   print("\n1. Settings")
   print("2. Exit")
   Choice = input("\n>")
   try:
       type(int(Choice))
   except Exception as e: 
       print("Oh no!\n I`ve encountered an error!" + e)           
   if Choice == 1:
       Settings()
   if Choice == 2:
       exit(0)

def Settings():
   pass # do the settings stuff

while True:
    Menu()
```

Comment: Isn't it better to just put the loop ***inside*** the `Menu` function and just call it once? This way you avoid all these recursive calls...

Answer (score 0):

```
Choice = (int(Choice))
```

The Choice variable is string type so you need to convert the type string to int.

Comment: Yes, thank you! You dont need to have ```( )``` in ```Choice = int(Choice)``` btw